# Removing index.php gives *no* 404 errors for wrong template groups

Tags: 404, index.php

I have the opposite problem to many: When I use [the official method to remove index.php](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html) and then enter an invalid url/template group, e.g.

http://www.example.com/blahblah

I **do not** get a 404 error, instead the most recently added page is shown.

Here's my setup:

- EE 2.9.2
- Strict URLs are enabled.
- The correct 404 template  is set.

Because most have the inverse situation I could not find much to help me debug this issue. If I delete the code that removes index.php I get a 404 as expected.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In the 404 template I embed a generic template, and the url to that template was wrong.

If you are stuck with the same issue, track your template nesting for clues. Good luck!